# Looking for a way to spawn a chest with custom axe

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've got an axe via this command (via command blocks)

```
 /give @p golden_axe 1 0 {display:{Name:"Thor's Axe",Lore:["The godliest","of the godliest."]},AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.maxHealth",Name:"generic.maxHealth",Amount:40,Operation:0,UUIDMost:69160,UUIDLeast:521589},{AttributeName:"generic.followRange",Name:"generic.followRange",Amount:32,Operation:0,UUIDMost:99396,UUIDLeast:851924},{AttributeName:"generic.knockbackResistance",Name:"generic.knockbackResistance",Amount:500,Operation:0,UUIDMost:76900,UUIDLeast:463228},{AttributeName:"generic.movementSpeed",Name:"generic.movementSpeed",Amount:0.5,Operation:0,UUIDMost:34152,UUIDLeast:644098},{AttributeName:"generic.attackDamage",Name:"generic.attackDamage",Amount:5,Operation:0,UUIDMost:85956,UUIDLeast:818955}],Unbreakable:1}
```

However, my intentions were to put it into a summoned chest command. So I tried this:

```
/setblock ~1 ~ ~ chest 0 replace {Items:[{golden_axe 0 1 {display:{Name:"Thor's Axe",Lore:["The godliest","of the godliest."]},AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.maxHealth",Name:"generic.maxHealth",Amount:40,Operation:0,UUIDMost:69160,UUIDLeast:521589},{AttributeName:"generic.followRange",Name:"generic.followRange",Amount:32,Operation:0,UUIDMost:99396,UUIDLeast:851924},{AttributeName:"generic.knockbackResistance",Name:"generic.knockbackResistance",Amount:500,Operation:0,UUIDMost:76900,UUIDLeast:463228},{AttributeName:"generic.movementSpeed",Name:"generic.movementSpeed",Amount:0.5,Operation:0,UUIDMost:34152,UUIDLeast:644098},{AttributeName:"generic.attackDamage",Name:"generic.attackDamage",Amount:5,Operation:0,UUIDMost:85956,UUIDLeast:818955}],Unbreakable:1}}]}
```

However then I get a JSON error about seperators:

```
[00:04:05] Data tag parsing failed: Unable to locate name/value separator for string: golden_axe {display:{Name:"Thor's Axe",Lore:["The godliest","of the godliest."]},AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.maxHealth",Name:"generic.maxHealth",Amount:40,Operation:0,UUIDMost:69160,UUIDLeast:521589},{AttributeName:"generic.followRange",Name:"generic.followRange",Amount:32,Operation:0,UUIDMost:99396,UUIDLeast:851924},{AttributeName:"generic.knockbackResistance",Name:"generic.knockbackResistance",Amount:500,Operation:0,UUIDMost:76900,UUIDLeast:463228},{AttributeName:"generic.movementSpeed",Name:"generic.movementSpeed",Amount:0.5,Operation:0,UUIDMost:34152,UUIDLeast:644098},{AttributeName:"generic.attackDamage",Name:"generic.attackDamage",Amount:5,Operation:0,UUIDMost:85956,UUIDLeast:818955}],Unbreakable:1}
```

Now I'm stumped. I found something like the one above; but it worked - but WITHOUT the custome attributes.

Is there anyway to put the axe :

```
    "{golden_axe {display:{Name:"Thor's Axe",Lore:["The godliest","of the godliest."]},AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.maxHealth",Name:"generic.maxHealth",Amount:40,Operation:0,UUIDMost:69160,UUIDLeast:521589},{AttributeName:"generic.followRange",Name:"generic.followRange",Amount:32,Operation:0,UUIDMost:99396,UUIDLeast:851924},{AttributeName:"generic.knockbackResistance",Name:"generic.knockbackResistance",Amount:500,Operation:0,UUIDMost:76900,UUIDLeast:463228},{AttributeName:"generic.movementSpeed",Name:"generic.movementSpeed",Amount:0.5,Operation:0,UUIDMost:34152,UUIDLeast:644098},{AttributeName:"generic.attackDamage",Name:"generic.attackDamage",Amount:5,Operation:0,UUIDMost:85956,UUIDLeast:818955}],Unbreakable:1}}]"
```

Into the chest? (summon command or setblock)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to insert a command into NBT data. You need to follow the correct format for NBT; the wiki lists data for the item format [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Player.dat_format#Item_structure).

In particular, you need to specify an `id` string, `Damage` short, `Count` byte, `Slot` byte, and `tag` compound. The `/give` syntax reflects all except `Slot`:

```
/give <player> <id> [Count] [Damage] {tag}
```

Therefore, with the following `/give` command:

```
/give @p minecraft:stone_sword 1 0 {Unbreakable:1b}
```

The data becomes:

```
{
    id:"minecraft:stone_sword",
    Damage:0s,
    Count:1b,
    tag:{
        Unbreakable:1b
    }
}
```

Your command will follow the same format, including the `Slot` tag as the `Items` list uses that tag to determine which slot in the inventory the item is in. Fixed command:

```
/setblock ~ ~1 ~ minecraft:chest 0 replace {Items:[{id:"minecraft:golden_axe",Count:1b,Slot:0b,Damage:0s,tag:{display:{Name:"Thor'sAxe",Lore:["Thegodliest","ofthegodliest."]},AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.maxHealth",Name:"generic.maxHealth",Amount:40,Operation:0,UUIDMost:69160,UUIDLeast:521589},{AttributeName:"generic.followRange",Name:"generic.followRange",Amount:32,Operation:0,UUIDMost:99396,UUIDLeast:851924},{AttributeName:"generic.knockbackResistance",Name:"generic.knockbackResistance",Amount:500,Operation:0,UUIDMost:76900,UUIDLeast:463228},{AttributeName:"generic.movementSpeed",Name:"generic.movementSpeed",Amount:0.5,Operation:0,UUIDMost:34152,UUIDLeast:644098},{AttributeName:"generic.attackDamage",Name:"generic.attackDamage",Amount:5,Operation:0,UUIDMost:85956,UUIDLeast:818955}],Unbreakable:1}}]}
```